# 12.10 and a slew of computer component issues

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, nvidia

**Problem**: installed Ubuntu 12.10 and everything went fine the first time. upon reaching the desktop all 4 of my monitors were working and of course out of order, which is no problem. immediately I noticed extensive lag, going to the unity bar to go to displays it would stagger, and in my case with the specs of my pc I would of expected a smooth fast ride. so instead of fixing the display I went and did all the updates and then rebooted. after coming back it still had the same issue, so I went and checked the update software and checked to see what driver it was using for my gtx 680, I tried all 5 of the options there and rebooted 1 at a time. not a single one worked at all. all the others either broke compiz and no windows or I didn't even have monitors. only the default one would work, but as mentioned caused serious lag but no screen tearing. so I decided to put the screens in order, upon doing that it wouldn't work correctly at all, the screens wouldn't even move, and if I got 1 to move it got stuck there for good. I tried reinstalling 3 more times, all other times it just failed to do any different.

**Question**: seeing 12.10 is new would it be better for me to try 12.04 is there going to be any fix from that lower edition, I figured 12.10 had better compatibility fixes.

Computer:

- **Running 4 Monitors**
- **Case**: Corsair Obsidian 800D
- **Motherboard**: Gigabyte x79-UP4 LGA 2011 Socket
- **Mobo Additionals**:  Gigabyte pci-e 802.11 b/g/n + bluetooth
- **CPU**: Intel I7-3930k 3.2 GHZ 12MB LGA 2011 Not Overclocked
- **GFX**: Nvidia MSI 2GB GTX 680
- **Memory**: Corsair Vengeance 2133MHz 16GB
- **Rom Drive**: LG 12x Blue-ray player and DVDRW Combo Drive
- **Thermal Display**: NZXT sentry lx aluminum dual bay digital fan control
- **Cooling**: Corsair hydro series h60 120mm liquid cooling
- **SSD**:128gb sandisk sata iii 6.0gb/s SSD <---where Ubuntu was installed
- **Data Drive**: 2tb sata iii 6gb/s 7200rpm 64mb cache 3.5" hd
- **Media Reader**: 12-in-one internal card reader
- **Power Supply**:Coolermaster silent pro gold 1000w power supply

Comment: Your question is nearly unreadable, please make complete sentences and remove those many "side remarks" which don't contribute to understanding your problem.

Comment: This site works generally in that way, that every post consists of **one** question and answers to that question - not many questions in one post.